# How do I get my footer to float left and right?

Tags: html, css, footer

I want the text to be on the right side of my footer and the images to be on the left. Every time I had the float: right to the "footer li.pictures" the background colour disappears.

Before adding float: right:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2cp9mkj.png

After adding float: right:
http://i60.tinypic.com/206y1rr.png

html:

```
<div class="events">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-12">
            <footer>

                    <ul class="links">
                        <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="links"><a href="vendors.html">Vendors</a></li>
                        <li class="links"><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                        <li class="links"><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                        <li class="links"><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li>
                    </ul>       

                    <ul class="pictures">
                        <li class="pictures">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/insta.png" alt="instagram icon">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pictures">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/twit.png" alt="twitter icon">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="pictures">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="images/face.png" alt="facebook icon">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
 .row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

.col {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0px 0;
}

footer {
    background-color:#343434;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: auto;
    font-family: 'billymedium';
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
}

footer a, a:visited {
    color: #b7b7b7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #5a8747;
}

footer img {
    max-width: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

footer ul.links, ul.pictures {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

footer li:first-child {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

footer li.links {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

footer li.pictures {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This is what I want it to look like:
http://i62.tinypic.com/2m46g4x.png

Answer (score 2):

Adding this CSS to your stylesheet should solve the problem:

```
footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Added, at it works. But why does it look like this now? 
http://tinypic.com/r/33e0v2t/8
I cant move the images up.

Comment: @karinaemm you can move the images up using the following CSS: `ul.pictures { margin-top: -5px; }`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clearing issue. You might have a .clearfix or .clear class made if this site is using a framework but basically it looks like this:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Add this inside of the "col span-12" div right before it ends:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

If you don't want to create a class, this also works:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```